# Can methods be defined in an object initializer without using the `function` keyword?

Tags: javascript, object

The other day I was a bit tired, I wrote this JavaScript code:

```js
var obj = {a(toto){console.log("func a: ", toto);} };
```

then I tried:

```js
obj.a("hello");
> func a:  hello
```

And it worked.

What I really meant to write was:

```js
var obj = {a: function(toto){console.log("func a: ", toto);} };
```

So my question is: why does the first code work?

Is there a doc somewhere that explains it, and do you think I can use it? (will it work in all browsers?)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is ECMAScript 6 syntax. Depending on your environment - node vs browser - it may or may not be advisable to use this syntax (e.g. not supported cross browser).

> Given the following code:
>
> `var obj = {   foo: function() {},   bar: function() {} };`
>
> You are now able to shorten this to:
>
> `var obj = { foo() {},   bar() {} };`

Reference:
[Method definitions (ES6)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Method_definitions)